# Rails 3.1: Server always processing as HTML, not JS

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm using rails 3.1.3. I want to use js.erb file as follow steps:
1. Create test action in posts controller:

```
def test
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js
    end
end
```

2. Define this action in routes.rb:

```
resource :posts do
    collection do
        get 'test'
    end
end
```

3. Create test.js.erb file:

```
$('#abc').append('<h1>something</h1>');
```

4. In the index.html.erb file:

```
<div id='abc'></div>
<%= link_to "Test", test_posts_path, :remote => true %>
```

However, I run and click to test link, it go to blank page with url `http://localhost:3000/posts/test` and the log server is:

```
Started GET "/posts/test" for 127.0.0.1 at Sat Feb 11 18:04:36 +0700 2012
Processing by PostsController#test as HTML
```

So, server not process as JS, jQuery in test.js.erb file is not executed. Can you explain for me why server process as HTML while in controller I define respond_to format.js?
I assume all responds in project are defined to format.html so my test action cannot respond to JS? If right, can I change it?
Thank you very much

UPDATE: In assets/javascripts/application.js need lines to use:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

Then it works.

Comment: Are `jquery` and `jquery-ujs` loaded by your `index.html.erb` ?

Answer (score 7):

Are you sure you have `gem 'jquery-rails'` in your Gemfile and `<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery", "jquery_ujs" %>` in your layout or `index.html.erb` template?

Comment: Oh, thank you. In rails 3.1.3, gem 'jquery-rails' is default. In assets/javascripts/application.js, I insert //= require jquery_ujs and it works. That's my fool when I deleted it

Comment: This solved a similar problem for me after hours of searching! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try `<%= link_to "Test", test_posts_path(:format => :js), :remote => true %>` to see what happen